# Is $\{12,18\} \cup ([-6,6] \setminus(-2,2))$ a compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the following set of real numbers compact?

$$\{12,18\} \cup ([-6,6] \setminus(-2,2))$$

It is obviously bounded (upper bound is $18$, lower bound is $-6$) but is it closed? I am not so familiar with topologic terms so please apologize if this question may seem a little dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As general fact, if $A$ is closed and $B$ is open in a space $X$, then $A \setminus B$ is closed, because $A \setminus B = A \cap (X \setminus B)$, where $X \setminus B$ is closed as $B$ is open, and a intersection of two (or finitely many) closed sets is closed.

In your case you have a union of a compact set $\{12,18\}$ and a closed set $[-6,6]\setminus (-2,2)$. As the latter is also compact, as a closed subset of the compact set $[-6,6]$ you have a union of two compact sets, which is always compact.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's closed. Your set can be written as $\{12,18\} \cup [-6,-2]\cup [2,6]$ and thus it is closed as finite union of closed sets.

Answer (score 2):

You can express it as a finite union of closed sets. Notice
$$[-6,6] \setminus (-2,2) = [-6,-2] \cup [2,6]$$
so
$$\{12,18\} \cup ([-6,6] \setminus (-2,2)) = \{ 12 \} \cup \{ 18 \} \cup [-6,-2] \cup [2,6]$$
A finite union of closed sets is closed, so your set is closed.

It's clearly bounded since it's contained in the set $[-6,18]$.